# how to switch languages in lubuntu 15.04 over XRDP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, lubuntu

It is very strange but I can not find the way how to switch languages in Lubuntu 15.04 when connected to it via XRDP. I've added new language in Preferences -> Keyboard input methods. It opened "IBus Preferences". There in the "Input Methods" tab I've added needed language:

[image]

Then I've added keyboard shortcut for switching the language (I've tried a lot of different ones, no one works):

[image]

But the switching does not work. First of all it does not react to the shortcut I've specified. And finally it does not type on desired language even if I specify it by clicking the icon in the systray.

[image]

Comment: See in [this article](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305) the section "To set Keyboard layout at the xrdp Login screen, perform the following steps".

Comment: maybe you can try to follow what this guy did : http://component-parts.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/fixing-uk-keyboard-mapping-for-xrdp.html
and this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1848639
I'm not sure you can make the switching work though

Answer (score 0):

The article
[Ubuntu 14.04 – How to install xrdp in Ubuntu 14.04](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305)
says this in its section of
"To set Keyboard layout at the xrdp Login screen, perform the following steps" :

> As explained above, with no special configuration, the xrdp login
>   screen keyboard layout is set to english by default.  if you need to
>   change it to another keyboard layout, you should proceed with the
>   following actions.
>
> 1. You go to the `/etc/xrdp` directory
> 2. you issue the command `setxkbmap -layout <%your layout%>` to define which keyboard map/layout to use
> 3. create a copy of the `km-0409.ini` file into the same directory. It seems that this is the default file used by xrdp to define the
>      keyboard layout. You will need to use sudo in order to be able to
>      write into the directory
> 4. Check that you have a backup of your file by typing the `dir` or `ls` command
> 5. update the file by issuing the following command `sudo xrdp-genkeymap km-0409.ini`

Comment: I am not talking about login screen. I am talking about system wide language switch.

Comment: Does this manipulation have any effect on the language when both XRDP and the target system have that same language?